# How do i allow access to directories with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow access to directories, while still maintaining the current configuration.

The Current configuration is this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php Index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

#Turn mow_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hiding .php extensions, and externally redirecting /dir/file.php to dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

##internally redirecting /dir/file.php to dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The thing is, this htaccess current configuration removes .php extension from files,
but i think, it's affecting directories, and restricting access to it.

Please what do i do to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php Index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

#Turn mow_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hiding .php extensions, and externally redirecting /dir/file.php to dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

##internally redirecting /dir/file.php to dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```